# why before embedding, have to make the item be sequential starting at zero

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, embedding, collaborative-filtering

I learn collaborative filtering from this bolg, [Deep Learning With Keras: Recommender Systems](https://www.johnwittenauer.net/deep-learning-with-keras-recommender-systems/).

The tutorial is good, and the code working well. [Here is my code](https://github.com/kk412027247/nn_collaborative_filtering/blob/master/nncf.py).

There is one thing confuse me, the author said,

> The user/movie fields are currently non-sequential integers representing some unique ID for that entity. We need them to be sequential starting at zero to use for modeling (you'll see why later).

```py
user_enc = LabelEncoder()
ratings['user'] = user_enc.fit_transform(ratings['userId'].values)
n_users = ratings['user'].nunique()
```

But he didn't seem to metion the reason, I don't why need to do that.Can some one explain for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embeddings are assumed to be sequential.

The first input of `Embedding` is the input dimension.
So, if the input exceeds the input dimension the value is ignored.
`Embedding` assumes that max value in the input is input dimension -1 (it starts from 0).

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding?hl=ja

As an example, the following code will generate embeddings only for input `[4,3]` and will skip the input `[7, 8]` since input dimension is 5.

I think it is more clear to explain it with tensorflow;

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5, 1, input_length=2))
input_array = np.array([[4,3], [7,8]])
model.compile('rmsprop', 'mse')
output_array = model.predict(input_array)
```

You can increase the input dimension to 9 and then you will get embeddings for both inputs.

You could increase the input dimension to  max number + 1 in the original data set, but this is not efficient.
It is actually similar to one-hot encoding where sequential data saves great amount of memory.

Comment: "Turns positive integers (indexes) into dense vectors of fixed size." Thx.